# Expanding the class from object

Tags: python, class

I have some classes:

```
class Window(object):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.wind_name = name
    def getWindowName(self):
        return 'wnd' + self.wind_name

class Control(object):
    def __init__(self, name, wnd):
        self.contrl_name = name
        setattr(self, 'getWindowName', wnd.getWindowName)
        setattr(self, 'wind_name', wnd.wind_name)
    def getControlName(self):
        return (self.getWindowName(), 'unk' + self.contrl_name)

class Button(Control):
    def __init__(self, name, wnd):
        super(Button, self).__init__(name, wnd)
    def getControlName(self):
        return (self.getWindowName(), 'btn' + self.contrl_name)

wnd = Window('MyApp')
btnOK = Button('OK', wnd)
btnOK.getControlName() # work ok., return ('wndMyApp', 'btnOK')
btnOK.wind_name = 'NewApp'
btnOK.getControlName() # does not work properly., return ('wndMyApp', 'btnOK')
```

How can I extend the class `Control`|`Button` from the object of class `Window` to access the functions `getWindowName` and field `wind_name` in objects `btnOK`?

Is there a way without creating a field `self.wnd = wnd` in class Control, or add method `setWindowName` in `Window`...?

I can not inherit class `Control` from the class `Window`! This is not logical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use property for attributes

```
class Window(object):
def __init__(self, name):
    self.wind_name = name

def getWindowName(self):
    return 'wnd' + self.wind_name

class Control(object):
    def __init__(self, name, wnd):
        self.contrl_name = name
        self.wnd = wnd
        setattr(self, 'getWindowName', wnd.getWindowName)

    def get_wind_name(self):
        return self.wnd.wind_name
    def set_wind_name(self, v):
        self.wnd.wind_name = v

    wind_name = property(get_wind_name, set_wind_name)
    def getControlName(self):
        return (self.getWindowName(), 'unk' + self.contrl_name)

class Button(Control):
    def __init__(self, name, wnd):
        super(Button, self).__init__(name, wnd)
    def getControlName(self):
        return (self.getWindowName(), 'btn' + self.contrl_name)

wnd = Window('MyApp')
btnOK = Button('OK', wnd)
print btnOK.getControlName() # work ok., return ('wndMyApp', 'btnOK')
btnOK.wind_name = 'NewApp'
print btnOK.getControlName()
```

Comment: Thanks, it would have worked, but I don't want to create the interim attribute to store the instance of the Window class. I just want to expand `Control.self` of `Window.self`.

Comment: This method is good, but if the Window class will be a lot of variables, it is very difficult to maintain.

Comment: You can use __getattr__ and __setattr__ methods to proxy all methods. But you can easily shoot yourself in the foot, so it is better to add methods by hand

Answer (score 2):

Python allows inheriting from multiple classes, i.e.

```
class Button(Control, Window):
    ...
```

But in this case you should know exactly what you are doing (speaking of Pythons Method Resolution Order (MRO)). I'd recommend reading this small book: [Python Attributes and Methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html).

Comment: Thanks, but I was interested in the solution without the inheritance, or the creation the interim attribute to store the instance of the `Window` class.